# Can I use Visual Studio 2015 to target .net framework 4.7?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015

I have Windows 10 Creators Update on my machine and I checked the registry key and found the *Value of the Release DWORD is 460798* (per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568(v=vs.110).aspx).

Yet, when I launched Visual Studio 2015 (Update 3) and the Target Framework drop down in a project properties does not show .NET Framework 4.7. The target .net platform page (http://getdotnet.azurewebsites.net/target-dotnet-platforms.html#) **does not show** .net framework 4.7 under VS 2015.

Can I even target .net framework 4.7 with VS 2015? If it is possible, what should I do?

Comment: Having the 4.7 runtime and having the "4.7 Targeting pack" to write code in 4.7 are two very different things.

Comment: Can please elaborate on this by giving some examples?

Comment: The targeting packs are now available https://www.microsoft.com/net/targeting

Comment: @Raghu in Visual Studio, for your project, open Properties, look for Application / Target framework. What you set here (.NET Framework 3.5, or 4.5 or 4,7) determines what you expect /require to be running on pcs that your app will run on. The .NET Framework features you can use are determined by this. This is the "target". If you wish to "target" Framework 4.7, but don't see ".NET Framework 4.7" listed as an option, you need the corresponding SDK or targeting pack. (Having the 4.7 runtime installed simply means you can run existing apps that require 4.7.)

Comment: Now, looking at a current VS 2015, 4.7 is one choice under Properties / Target framework, so can be targetted without further downloads. There is also an option "Install other frameworks...", which takes you to Microsoft's SDK page. There, you can download 4.7.1. [Or whatever is the latest, at the time you are reading this.]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Edit: The [targeting pack](https://www.microsoft.com/net/targeting) is now available for earlier versions also as of 2017-05-02.

Microsoft hasn't yet released the .NET 4.7 targeting pack for earlier versions of Visual Studio. It will come "soon" when they also release the framework for earlier Windows versions.

See the section Support in their [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/04/05/announcing-the-net-framework-4-7/).

Comment: I just downloaded the Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7 Developer Pack, but it will not install on my Windows 10 PC, probably because the Windows 10 Anniversary Update has not yet been able to install successfully.

Comment: You're going to need the Windows 10 Creators Update or you can download .NET 4.7 here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55170

Answer (score 7):

It is available now .We can target .net framework 4.7 with VS 2015. It is possible,

**Download and install this in the development PC.**

[.Net developer pack for Vs 2015](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework/net472)

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.

Comment: The link is now a 404

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can!

The .NET Framework 4.7 Developer Pack lets developers build applications that target the .NET Framework 4.7 by using Visual Studio 2015.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3186612/the-net-framework-4-7-developer-pack-and-language-packs

** Remember to restart your workstation after installation.