# Selecting .Net Framework Version in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, docusignapi

I have installed .NET Framework 4.7 on machine running Windows 7. I am running Visual Studio 2010. WHen I go to Project > Properties > Application, I do not see version 4.7 available in the drop down list. The highest version is 4.

How do I upgrade the project to 4.7?

What I really need is TLS 1.2 for DocuSign APIs.

Comment: You may need to update your version of VS. See [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies) on .net version compatibility with Visual Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last version of .NET Framework that Visual Studio 2010 supports is, as you've realized .NET Framework 4.0.

[Here's a list of .NET Framework Versions and Dependencies.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies)

You would need to update to one of the latest Visual Studio updates, preferably 2017.

<strike>I'm not 100% certain if 2015 can handle it, but it could possibly considering the binary compatibility between 2015 and 2017. But this is just a guess.</strike>

Correction: [Version 4.7 is possible with 2015.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47922786/5879778) However I still recommend updating to Visual Studio 2017 if you have the ability to. It's free.

Comment: Thanks but they don't want to buy it.

Comment: Could i do it by changing replacing project reference to reference assemblies in 4.7?

Comment: Do you absolutely need the professional license for this task? Because like I mentioned, Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition is free. That being said, _could you do it_? I mean.. Possibly? But it's more than likely not going to be trivial. In the off chance you get it to "work" you're going to run the risk of a lot of incompatibility issues with the 2010 binaries with the 2017 versions.

Comment: I am technically in an enterprise environment, so can't use community. I am downloading it to try it out. But for production-related development I have to use Professional or higher. You are right, I am not inclined to break my head dealing with various incompatibilities.