# 'char' does not contain a definition for 'MinValue'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, char, .net-4.7.2

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 .NET Framework 4.7.2. and I tried to access `MinValue` from a `char` but I get an error saying there's no definition.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.minvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2

My project has no build errors and I've included `using System`. How can I correct this error?

[image]

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding your solution.

Comment: By the way, VS 2015 needs a targeting pack for `.NET 4.7+`. Do you have that? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43420178/can-i-use-visual-studio-2015-to-target-net-framework-4-7

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56119

Comment: I did. I also created a brand new project, starting from scratch. Still have the issue.

Comment: What does the statement `char minValue = char.MinValue;` followed by `return null;` accomplish? Is this just test code or something? I've never tried using `char.MinValue` before. Does a `Nullable<char>` work for your situation? Not an attempt to answer your question. Just asking if it might be a better solution.

Comment: Do you have `using System;` declared?

Comment: @DavidTansey `System` is not required for `char.MinValue` (plus they specified that it was added in the question).

Answer (score 0):

While I previously have installed the developer pack for the .NET 4.7.2, it must have gotten corrupted somehow. I [re-downloaded](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/thank-you/net472-developer-pack) the developer pack and ran a repair, which fixed it.