# Upgrade TargetFramework for C++ project

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, c++-cli

I have changed target framework from `<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>` to `<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.8</TargetFrameworkVersion>` for a C++ project.
And now I'm getting an exception:

> Exception thrown: 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException'
> in System.Configuration.dll log4net:ERROR Exception while reading
> ConfigurationSettings. Check your .config file is well formed XML.
>
> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration
> system failed to initialize ---> System.TypeInitializationException:
> The type initializer for 'System.Uri' threw an exception. --->
> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
> 'System.UriParser' threw an exception. --->
> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
> 'System.Runtime.Versioning.BinaryCompatibility' threw an exception.
> ---> System.ArgumentException: String cannot be of zero length. Parameter name: frameworkName    at
> System.Runtime.Versioning.BinaryCompatibility.ParseFrameworkName(String
> frameworkName, String& identifier, Int32& version, String& profile)
> at
> System.Runtime.Versioning.BinaryCompatibility.ParseTargetFrameworkMonikerIntoEnum(String
> targetFrameworkMoniker, TargetFrameworkId& targetFramework, Int32&
> targetFrameworkVersion)    at
> System.Runtime.Versioning.BinaryCompatibility.ReadTargetFrameworkId()
> at
> System.Runtime.Versioning.BinaryCompatibility.get_AppWasBuiltForFramework()
> at System.Runtime.Versioning.BinaryCompatibility..cctor()    --- End
> of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.UriParser..cctor()
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.Uri..cctor()    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem..ctor()    at
> System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.EnsureConfigurationSystem()
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.PrepareConfigSystem()    at
> System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.get_AppSettings()    at
> log4net.Util.SystemInfo.GetAppSetting(String key)

My investigation gives me the reason: while compilation VS2015 adds `[assembly: TargetFramework("", FrameworkDisplayName = "")]`. That's why I can't add the correct `TargetFrameworkAttribute` manually. And this automatically added attribute causes an exception as the target framework can't be an empty string.

Do you have any advice, on how could I fix this problem?

**Update:**
Well, I've enabled logging as Hans Passant said. But I had no luck. As there was no word about .Net 4.0 and Visual Studio created  correct file `%temp%\.NETFramework,Version=v4.8.AssemblyAttributes.cpp`, but the content of the file:

> #using <mscorlib.dll> [assembly: System::Runtime::Versioning::TargetFrameworkAttribute(L"",
> FrameworkDisplayName=L"")];

Nevertheless, I found a hack - I'm adding the required attribute manually.
To do it I defined a variable in the project file:

```
 <GenerateTargetFrameworkAttribute>false</GenerateTargetFrameworkAttribute>
```

This variable avoids the automatic creation of the `TargetFrameworkAttribute`. So I can add the correct attribute from my code:

```
[assembly:TargetFramework(".NETFramework,Version=v4.8", FrameworkDisplayName = ".NET Framework 4.8")];
```

With this workaround, I can start the application and it seems to work everything... but I do not really like it.

Comment: I don't think 2015 supports 4.8, e.g see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43420178/can-i-use-visual-studio-2015-to-target-net-framework-4-7/43420229, you need to install the 4.8 targeting pack

Comment: Well, I have installed .Net 4.8 developer pack. And I'm able to select .Net 4.8 for C# projects. The attribute `TargetFramework` will be added for C# projects correctly. After I've changed the target version for the C++ project I see, that VS shows correct references for System.* assemblies. But compiled exe references assemblies form .Net 4.0...

Comment: Use Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run > "MSBuild project build output verbosity" = Diagnostic.  Rebuild and the Output window now gives a lot more details.  Search for "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute", that's where things go wrong.  In a nutshell, it generates a small file that should be named .NETFramework,Version=v4.8.AssemblyAttributes.cpp in order to get the project setting compiled into the output.